# Are these contacts grounded?

Tags: grounding, schematic

[This](http://www.pong-story.com/1tl200blak_sch.pdf) is the schematic for the Magnavox Odyssey.

Looking at some of the "GAME CARD 1" connectors, can it be assumed that 9, 38, 28, 42, etc, are simply not connected?

[image]

In other places, "NC" is specified when they are not grounded or connected to anything else (FLIP-FLOP/BALL).

[image]

Comment: never assume anything ... it would depend on the game card ... it is possibke that one of the games uses those signals

Comment: Yes they do. However, the schematic only described the first game card. I think they are disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to see which part of the connector is the pin, and which is the socket. The rectangle in the center is the pin, and the 'cup' around it is the socket.

So on the game card connector the connections on the right are the sockets that the card plugs into, the connections on the left are the pins on the game card. The sockets in question, 9, 38, 28, etc., are connected to the signals from the game, the pins for those are not used on the card shown, but may be for other cards so they are not labeled NC.

On the other connector, which is for a flip-flop module, the pins on the module are connected to the flip-flop circuit, but the socket on the main board has no connection there, so they have labeled it NC.

You can also see some of the sockets on the game card connector that are labeled NC, so it appears that the convention they are using is to only label unused sockets on the main board as NC.

Comment: As an aside, that whole circuit is pretty interesting. I once breadboarded some parts of it and made a circuit to display a line modulated by the audio from my stereo on a TV set. The main game is based on three basic transistor circuits and some switching diodes, amazing what they were able to do with that.

Comment: Thank you GodJihyo and everyone who answered. I agree, it's very interesting. I'm actually simulating parts of it in multisim in the hopes to deducing any logic which I can translate in to a software emulator, or possibly simulate it the way SPICE does, though that's a difficult topic I feel. So far, the HSYNC and VSYNC circuits are simulated but little else. I'll continue with hope and curiosity.